# Passing THIS into an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression

Tags: javascript, this

Is there any way to pass `this` into an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, without resolving to `var that = this` (which isn't applicable on some cases)?

Tried the following but with no luck:

```
(function(that) {
    console.log(that);
})(this)
```

Comment: what's this in the context? are you calling that function on an object or in a function context? .. the function.apply(context,arguments) form could be what you're looking for ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for this purpose. For example:

```
(function() {
    console.log(this); // whatever that was specified in the "call" method
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(that) {
    console.log(that);
})(this);
```

The code should work, make sure there is no code before it without a semicolon.

```
 (function(that) {
        console.log(that);
 })(this) // if here is no semicolon, the next code will be syntax error.
 (function(that) {
        console.log(that);
 })(this);
```

You could try the code below, which will be ok even the code before it omit the semicolon.

```
!function(that) {
    console.log(that);
}(this);
```