# Gulp-Uglify: $(void 0) when caching DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, gulp-uglify

When using gulp-uglify and caching DOM elements (with jQuery), uglify makes `$(void 0)` out of `$(this)`.

```
$(document).on("click", "sth", () => {
    var $this = $(this);
    ...
});
```

Will result in this:

```
$(document).on("click", "sth", function() {
    var e = $(void 0);
    ...
});
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. If you have a problem with a gulp task, post the gulp task. We can't possibly guess what it looks like. The stock `gulp-uglify` can't handle arrow functions, so you're either using `babel` or `UglifyJS2`, but there's no way to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions [do not bind `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this):

> An arrow function does not create its own this context, so `this` has its original meaning from the enclosing context.

That means `this` in your example refers to the `this` of the surrounding scope. Since your arrow function is not inside another function, the `this` refers to the global `this`.

In a browser the global `this` [refers to the `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Global_context). However I'm guessing you're using `babel` with the `babel-preset-es2015` preset. In this case `babel` will assume that [your code is inside an ES6 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973442/how-to-stop-babel-from-transpiling-this-to-undefined). Inside an ES6 module the value of `this` is `undefined`.

That means `babel()` will transpile this code:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Into this code:

```
var $this = $(undefined);
```

Next up you have `uglify()`, which tries to compress the above line as much as possible. To this end it exploits the fact that [`void 0` evaluates to `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452341/what-does-void-0-mean) and since `void 0` is shorter than `undefined` you end up with this:

```
var e = $(void 0);
```

How do you fix this? Easy. Don't use an arrow function:

```
$(document).on("click", "sth", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    ...
});
```