# Firebase TypeError: Cannot read property 'ac' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, rollupjs, bublejs

I use this simple code to authenticate on my web app

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

After authentication I get the following error in my browser: 'Firebase TypeError: Cannot read property 'ac' of undefined'  which seems to point to an error here:

```
        h.set = function(a, b, c) {
            var d = this.aa(a, c)
              , e = this
              , f = Si(this, a.B);
            return f.set(d, b).then(function() {
                return f.get(d)
            }).then(function(b) {
                "local" != a.B || this.ac || (e.W[d] = b);
            })
        }
        ;
```

I'm compiling my es6 code using rollup and buble. Also please note that on the server response it looks like I'm successfully authenticating.

Because I got the following response:

```
{
 "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyCustomTokenResponse",
 "idToken": "token",
 "refreshToken": "refreshtoken",
 "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related to: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/121
[How to stop babel from transpiling 'this' to 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973442/how-to-stop-babel-from-transpiling-this-to-undefined)

Quoting: "The thing that is causing you trouble is that in an ES6 module, this is undefined, whereas in the "script" case, this varies depending on the environment, like window in a browser script or exports in CommonJS code."

Comment: I think this might be helpful, but the problem is I'm using rollup and buble, and the link only responds on how to do it in babel

Answer (score 0):

@bojeil I actually tried your suggestion and even changed my whole transpiler from buble to babel, just to get it going. Same result.

In the end, an update from v4.2.0 to v4.3.0 was release just 13 hours before this was posted and fixed the issue.

So to whomever have the same issue, updating firebase.