# How to stop babel from transpiling 'this' (used as an IIFE argument) to 'void 0'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I want to transpile ES6 to ES5 since we're forced to support IE11 and have some trouble with modern scripts. My bundle contains Sweetalert2 and `window` got `undefined` after babel.

Input

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global.Sweetalert2 = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict'; 
    // ...
```

After babel processing:

```
(function (global, factory) {
  (typeof exports === "undefined" ? "undefined" : _typeof2(exports)) === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() : typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) : global.Sweetalert2 = factory();
})(void 0, function () {
  'use strict';
// ....
```

I found [How to stop babel from transpiling 'this' to 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973442/how-to-stop-babel-from-transpiling-this-to-undefined) and since the preset-es2015 package [is considered as deprecated](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-es2015), I thought that using `@babel/preset-env` the up2date repalcement for my babel7 is `"esmodules": false` but it's not working.

.babelrc

```
{
  "ignore": ["gulpfile.js"],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "esmodules": false
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why not *actually* use `window` instead of `this` (which usually only resolves to Window in a global context)?

Comment: @user2864740 As I said, this is not my source. Please ask this question to the Sweetalert2 developers :)