# "this" context not available in JS file (Webpack 4)

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have migrated my webpack from 3.8.1 to 4.41.2. I have been facing the issue of "this" context in standalone javascript file. Please check below code:

> util.js

```
export const calculateSum = (a,b) => {
    this.sum = 0;
    this.sum += a + b;
    return this.sum;
};
```

Please note that above is sample code depicting the issue.

While using webpack 3.8.1 I was able to use "this" object as used in above example but after migrating to 4.41.2, I am not able to do so.

I have many such cases in very large code base, so it is not feasible to change the code everywhere. Could not find such option in webpack config.

How can I fix in the new version of webpack?

Comment: “I am not able to do so” – please describe more clearly what this means: are there any error messages? What is the expected behavior? What is the observed behavior?

Comment: @PatrickHund While using webpack 3.8.1 each file had it's own context which was available in `this`, which was nothing but plain javascript object. After upgrading it to 4.41.2 `this` context is not available and now value of `this` is undefined, hence in the code wherever i have used something like `this.something` is breaking because value of `this` is now undefined.
I hope this clears your question, let me know if you have any other doubt.

Comment: @HridayModi Create a little git repo which reproduces the issue and I will take a look.

Comment: How looks webpack result of this function?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6379) , Webpack turns "this" to undefined in class definitions.

The dev said they fixed the `this` issue in Webpack 4, `maybe you use global webpack installation`

If the webpack installation doesn't work, you can try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973442/how-to-stop-babel-from-transpiling-this-to-undefined-and-inserting-use-str), it might be the Babel problem.

Babel 6, Babel 7 has different solution, you can try the config based on your Babel version.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
output: {
  globalObject: 'this'
}

Comment: Hey, I have tried this before posting the question but bad luck, it did not work.