# UMD modules in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, umd

The UMD module definition is approximately this:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['exports', 'b'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object' && typeof exports.nodeName !== 'string') {
        // CommonJS
        factory(exports, require('b'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory((root.commonJsStrict = {}), root.b);
    }
}(this, function (exports, b) {
    //use b in some fashion.

    // attach properties to the exports object to define
    // the exported module properties.
    exports.action = function () {};
}));
```

The issue is that Chrome Extensions don't support any of these methods of exporting the module:

- `define` doesn't exist
- `exports` doesn't exist
- `this` isn't bound to `window`

For this reason, it seems that UMD modules fail in Chrome Extension environments. Is there any workaround to get a UMD module to correctly export into the `window` object in a Chrome Extension?

Comment: Extension environment is a standard browser environment so you can only use the standard ES modules directly. To use other types you either need to use a compiler/bundler or define those things it's looking for, like a global `exports` object or `define` function (you can write it yourself or find an existing one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wOxxOm has correctly pointed out, the Chrome Extension environment is the same as the browser, and `this` is indeed bound to `window`, so UMD modules can and should work with extensions.

It turns out the actual problem is that babel was producing a bundle with `this` replaced by `undefined`, which is the problem outlined and resolved in this issue: [How to stop babel from transpiling 'this' to 'undefined' (and inserting "use strict")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973442/how-to-stop-babel-from-transpiling-this-to-undefined-and-inserting-use-str).